# The performance difference between default new operator and std::malloc

Tags: c++, std

I am use google benchmark to run benchmarks for `boost/singleton_pool`. And I happen to make a template class which overloads the `new` and `delete` with `std::malloc` and `std::free`:

```
    template <typename Derived>
    class Standard
    {
      public:
        static void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
            return std::malloc(size);
        }

        static void operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t) {
            std::free(ptr);
        }
    };
```

I tested some classes, like `int` and `Standard<int>` with gooogle benchmark framework and I found that this template wrapper will have performance effects. It seems that for class `T`, `Standard<T>` is a bit faster than `T` itself.

I'm very confused about this. I thought default `new` and `delete` also uses `std::malloc` and `std::free`. Why they are different??

A minimal reproducable binary:(need google benchmark framework to compile)

```
#include "evelyn/PoolPolicy.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

template <size_t N>
struct Block
{
    int8_t data[N];
};

template <typename T>
class Standard
{
public:
    static void *operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        return std::malloc(size);
    }

    static void operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t)
    {
        std::free(ptr);
    }
};


using A = Standard<int>;
using B = int;

class PoolFixture : public benchmark::Fixture
{
public:
    void SetUp(const ::benchmark::State &state)
    {
    }

    void TearDown(const ::benchmark::State &state)
    {
    }
};

auto constexpr ITERATE_TIME = 1000;

BENCHMARK_F(PoolFixture, without_pool_only_allocate)
(benchmark::State &state)
{
    using Block = Block<10>;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < ITERATE_TIME; ++i)
        {
            auto ptr = new Block;
        }
    }
}

BENCHMARK_F(PoolFixture, with_pool_only_allocate)
(benchmark::State &state)
{
    using Block = Standard<Block<10>>;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < ITERATE_TIME; ++i)
        {
            auto ptr = new Block;
        }
    }
}

BENCHMARK_F(PoolFixture, without_pool_allocate_and_delete_1)
(benchmark::State &state)
{
    using Block = Block<10>;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < ITERATE_TIME; ++i)
        {
            auto ptr = new Block;
            delete ptr;
        }
    }
}

BENCHMARK_F(PoolFixture, with_pool_allocate_and_delete_1)
(benchmark::State &state)
{
    using Block = Standard<Block<10>>;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < ITERATE_TIME; ++i)
        {
            auto ptr = new Block;
            delete ptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return std::malloc(size);` don't you have to multiply by the sizeof(Derived)?

Comment: Because `new`/`delete` does not only allocate memory, they also construct/destruct objects in the allocated memory. `malloc()` and `free()` only does half of the way.

Comment: I only use `malloc` and `free` to overload `new`/`delete`. Do you mean that if I overload them, they will not do construct/destruct any more?

Comment: Yes, your implementation is probably fine for built-in integral types, but for objects, it's incomplete. It's probably undefined behaviour but I did not check that claim.

Comment: But even for built-in types, there is big performance difference. I don't think that's because of constructor or destructor.

Comment: Oversimplifying a bit - to create a free-store C++ [Object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object), 2 things need happen: (1) raw-memory needs to be allocated and (2) the object needs to be created in that raw-memory.  `new` does (1) and (2), `malloc` only does (1).

Comment: For performance questions you need to (1) show how the test was compiled, (2) a [mcve] for the test, (3) the results.

Comment: I don't think so. Please note that I use `malloc` to overload the `new` operator. In C++, `new` operator only responsible for allocate memory, which means even if I overload it, there is still constructor called.

Comment: @JunhuiZhu I'm not aware of the implementation details, but even without taking into account the object creation, it probably is still more than just a plain `malloc()`, maybe some stuff to keep track of the size, etc...

Comment: Nope, the constructor is not called with `malloc()` you can easily check that, do write a simple test --> [Proof here](https://godbolt.org/z/xcx9rKEfd)

Comment: The other way to know the constructor isn't called is by recognizing that there's no type information in `malloc`, not to mention is a C function in which language constructors do not exist.

Comment: there is no contradiction. Default `new` and `delete` use `std::malloc` and `free`. You do that too but not more, so why is it a surprise that yours takes less time than the proper ones?

Comment: to explain the time difference (for the case of eg `int`) you would need to post a [mcve].

Comment: I have put a reproducible example in my problem details. Guys you can compile it with google benchmark and run it.

Comment: Are you aware that `Standard<Block<10>>` does not contain a `Block<10>`? Just run `std::cout << sizeof(Block<10>) << ", " << sizeof(Standard<Block<10>>) << '\n';` and it will tell you that one is size 10 and the other size 1. So `new Block<10>` and `new Standard<Block<10>>` do not allocate the same amount of memory.

Comment: Where is `benchmark::DoNotOptimize`? without it optimizer can remove you code under test completely leading to invalid results Here is demo where it happened and results are ridiculous: https://quick-bench.com/q/hywNlzzlqUW0BdtVYNUWawBiN84 my attempt to fix this properly ends with timeouts on this site.

Comment: @Frodyne This should be posted as an answer since it is the reason of the performances difference.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: Here I'm focusing on fact that performance test is written incorrectly. I do not analyzed if tested code is valid.

---

Basically your test is invalid.

- for [clang no difference](https://quick-bench.com/q/0HS-pyRTG6czj0kqO2Cf0-7tBKE)
- for [gcc something fishy happens](https://quick-bench.com/q/hywNlzzlqUW0BdtVYNUWawBiN84)

Optimizer removed large portion of your testing code leading to invalid results. Also this memory leak is disturbing. Please read carefully [machine code produced](https://godbolt.org/z/dTf8Pos9a) - for a first glance you can see lots of code has been removed by optimizer.

Here are my attempt to disable optimizations in your test (note I had to decrease `ITERATE_TIME` value).

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

template <size_t N>
struct Block
{
    int8_t data[N];
};

template <typename T>
class Standard
{
public:
    static void *operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        return std::malloc(size);
    }

    static void operator delete(void *ptr, std::size_t)
    {
        std::free(ptr);
    }
};


using A = Standard<int>;
using B = int;

class PoolFixture : public benchmark::Fixture
{
public:
    void SetUp(const ::benchmark::State &state)
    {
    }

    void TearDown(const ::benchmark::State &state)
    {
    }
};

BENCHMARK_F(PoolFixture, without_pool_only_allocate)
(benchmark::State &state)
{
    using Block = Block<10>;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        auto ptr = new Block;
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(*ptr);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr);
    }
}

BENCHMARK_F(PoolFixture, with_pool_only_allocate)
(benchmark::State &state)
{
    using Block = Standard<Block<10>>;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        auto ptr = new Block;
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(*ptr);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr);
    }
}

BENCHMARK_F(PoolFixture, without_pool_allocate_and_delete_1)
(benchmark::State &state)
{
    using Block = Block<10>;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        auto ptr = std::make_unique<Block>();
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(*ptr);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr);
    }
}

BENCHMARK_F(PoolFixture, with_pool_allocate_and_delete_1)
(benchmark::State &state)
{
    using Block = Standard<Block<10>>;
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        auto ptr = std::make_unique<Block>();
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(*ptr);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ptr);
    }
}
```

Sadly quick-bench.com timeouts on this version so can't provide demo

Writing valid performance test in C++ and full of crafty traps, you can measure wrong thing, so be careful.

Comment: It may be worth to mention that `Standard<blablabla>` does not make `Standard` to "magically" hold a `blablabla` as Frodyne pointed out in comments.

Comment: I've focused on fact that benchmark is incorrectly written and ignored other issues. That is why added "disclaimer".

Answer (score 0):

The standard version of `operator new` does more than your version does. If the allocation request fails (i.e., `malloc` returns `NULL`), it first calls a possible series of user-specified “new handlers”, and if none of those fixes the problem, it throws an exception. It **never** returns a `NULL` pointer. For details, see paragraph 1) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).